# Error: Could not find or load main class 2.lib

Tags: java, javafx

I need help I install JavaFX on my Macbook air but I keep getting this Error:

```
Could not find or load main class 2.lib
```

even though I updated the arguments on the runtime

```
--module-path /Users/lily/Developer/javafx-sdk-18 2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

and added the jar files. does anyone knows how to fix this on Mac.

Comment: You should quote your path if space is important

Answer (score 1):

The blank in the path name between 18 and 2 is suspicious. Remove that. Or more precisely rename that path to something without blank.

Comment: Or quote the entire path if it really does contain spaces.

Comment: I remore the space  --module-path/Users/lilliamcastro/Developer/javafx-sdk-18 2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml. but now it givies me another error Unrecognized option: --module-path/Users/lilliamcastro/Developer/javafx-sdk-18
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Put a space after `--module-path`